# AllowAnonymous attribute make Authorize ignored

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've a admin dashboard project that need global authorization and I set it up on

```
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
    }
```

That code make all my controller is being authorize.. And there is a controller that has [AllowAnonymous] attribute.. However I've sudden change request that an action on this controller need to be authorize..

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class AuthController : Controller
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult BumbaSection()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

This is not working, I still can access this BumbaSection action.. Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: First, you don't need to register the AuthorizeAttribute in the global filters, it's already part of the mvc framework. How do you authenticate, and how do you store your roles, show us your code regarding that.

Answer (score 3):

After I peek the authorize code, This part of code make the authorize not working :

```
public virtual void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
  //code here

  if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof (AllowAnonymousAttribute), true) || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof (AllowAnonymousAttribute), true))
      return;

  //code here    
}
```

Override this piece of code in authorize attribute class and my code is start working.. Maybe this will usefull for who that have some problem with me